# Visual Studios C# - Adding, reading, removing data from Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to read/add data to a database in Visual studios. I have connected to a Database via

> Server Explorer -> Data Connections - > Add new data connection.

When  a button is clicked, I would like to read values from a textbox and add data to this database. 
I'm a very new to Visual basics, how could I do this via code? Could you explain the procedure to do this?(I did a bit of SQL couple of years ago, so I have a bit of knowledge) Or link me to a website which explains this.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of resources out there about `databinding`:

[Windows Forms Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx)

[Bind Data to WinForms Controls](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2004/02/01/bind-data-to-winforms-controls.aspx)

[Data Binding and Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx)

[Creating Client Data Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0y4a0f6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)